# Organizing records to classes

Tags: python, class

I'm planning to develop a genetic algorithm for a series of acceleration records in a search to find optimum match with a target.

At this point my data is array-like with a unique ID column, X,Y,Z component info in the second, time in the third etc...

That being said each record has several "attributes". Do you think it would be beneficial to create a (records) class considering the fact I will want to to do a semi-complicated process with it as a next step?

Thanks

Comment: Do you do many operations/calculations on the same unique set of data? If yes, then use class. If you just do calculation on many different set of data, better just use dictionary to store your data.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. Basically I want to:

1. Take the unique set of data
2. Filter it so that just a subset is considered (filter parameters can be time of recording for example)
3. Use a genetic algorithm the filtered data to match on average a target.

Step 3 is irrelevant to the post, I just wanted to give the big picture in order to make my question more clear.